# What are the consequences of handling a rejected promise too early?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

> Handling a rejected promise too early has consequences further down the promise chain.

What kind of consequences can be there? In which cases should early handling of rejections be avoided and in which cases should early handling of rejections be preferred?

Comment: further down the chain you may be expecting some sort of data which the rejection handling isn't providing - really not easy to contrive an example though

Comment: @JaromandaX still explain in an answer, please.

Comment: How? it's not easy to contrive an example

Comment: @JaromandaX Leave the example - you can explain just the theory in an answer.

Comment: This was a really awful edit. Better read the [version before it](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise$revision/1611390), and the [*Using promises* guide](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) instead. While this sentence is bad, the following section about russian dolls really makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The critical part to understand is that catch() also returns a promise.

Consider the following example. Since the intermediate catch has no return BUT catch() itself returns a promise, the final catch never fires and the final then() does ... receiving a result of `undefined` from the prior catch() promise

```js
const func = (val) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
       // not really asynchronous, only contrived for demo
       val === 1 ? resolve(val) : reject('Oooops')
  }).catch(err=> {console.log('Err in func catch:', err)})      
}

func(200).then(res=> console.log('Then res=', res))// receives undefined from prior catch
         .catch(err=> console.log('Never gets called'))
```

So you could do several things differently here depending on preferred logic.

You could return a different expected value from the intermediate catch and look for that in the final then, or return another rejected promise or thrown error to be caught in the final catch().

Or...don't use the middle catch at all if it serves no value intercepting it.

---

Example use case for using the intermediate catch would be:

A map() of request urls passed through a function that returns the request promise back to your map array but you are OK if not all succeed.

Without the intermediate catch intercepting, the whole chain would break at first bad request. Instead you can return something from intermediate catch that you filter out in a `Promise.all().then()`